# Are dynamic menus an anti-pattern?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, menu, information-architecture, mega-menu

I'm analyzing the menu of construction management software. I don't know if I don't have the same user mental models and what was the research behind those decisions, but I wonder based on HCI and usability research, are those antipatterns?

*Procore*

**Project 2 Home Screen**
[image]

**Switch Project**
[image]

**Project tools "local links of the project"**
[image]

**Customizing Menu**
[image]

*Fieldwire*

**Photos**
[image]

**Plans**
[image]

**Switch Project**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine someone with a screen reader not wanting to re-listen to the entire menu once it changed.  They may not even know it had changed. So at the very least, you are creating an inaccessible experience.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are the NN/G articles on mega-menus.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-work-well/

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-gone-wrong/

The decision for menu customization looks like workflow related. Looks like there would be few specialist roles with specialist needs, and those users would just use one or two features, but frequently.